# Shuffle array from text file (seg fault)

Tags: c, arrays, random, segmentation-fault, shuffle

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Accepts: command line input
// Returns: 0 if no error

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
int x = 0, i, lCount = 0, maxLen = 0;
    char line[500], *temp;
    FILE *file = fopen("names.txt", "r" );
//  check if file exists
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
//  Gets lines, max length of string    
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL){
        lCount++;
    if (strlen(line) > maxLen)
        maxLen = strlen(line);
    }
    rewind(file);
    char *lArray[lCount];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        lArray[x] = malloc(strlen(line));
        if (lArray[x] == NULL){
            printf("A memory error occurred.\n");
            return(1);
        }
            strcpy(lArray[x], line);
//  change \n to \0
    lArray[x][strlen(lArray[x])-1] = '\0';
    x++;
    }
    printf("File %s has %d lines with maximum length of %d characters\n",
        argv[1], lCount, maxLen);
    printf("Original Array\n");
    for (x = 0; x < lCount; x++)
        printf("%2d %s\n", x, lArray[x]);
//  Shuffle array
    srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL));
    for (x = lCount - 1; x >= 0; x--){
        i = (int) rand() % lCount;
        temp = lArray[x];
        lArray[x] = lArray[i];
        lArray[i] = temp;
    }
    printf("\nShuffled Array\n");
    for (x = 0; x < lCount; x++)
        printf("%2d %s\n", x, lArray[x]);
//  free allocated memory
    for (x = 0; x < lCount; x++)
        free(lArray[x]);
    free(lArray);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

For the most part I have all the code written out. Only 2 problems, a segmentation fault at the end of the output and I want to change it around a bit to make it cleaner. any suggestions? Thanks!
It should also have this structure:

```
/* Read the file into an array */
/* Count lines and maximum length */
/* Compute maximum width for array */
/* Get file pointer to the beginning */
/* Reserve memory for a dynamic array of strings */
/* Read a line and store in allocated memory */
/* Turn the \n into \0 */
/* Print lines from array (test) */
/* Shuffle array */
/* Print lines from array (test) */
/* Free memory and close file */
```

Comment: `man perror` because "Cannot open file" is an infuriatingly useless error message.

Comment: `free(lArray)` is likely causing the seg fault. This variable is defined on the stack not the heap.

Comment: There's no need to make two passes.  Unless you later use the space that you are currently over-allocating for each line, just read the line and allocate the correct amount for that line.  `strdup` would be helpful here.